# Setting processor affinity within a Linux kernel module

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel-module

I was wondering if there was way of setting (and getting) processor affinity in a kernel module without having to change the kernel code.

Edit:
I do know about "sched.h" but surely that is user space code and hence cannot be included in the kernel module code. So I want to know how to achieve the same functionality in the kernel.

Answer (score 0):

[sched_setaffinity](http://linux.die.net/man/2/sched_setaffinity) can do the trick for you, without having to change the kernel code

Comment: I did try that and got an error along the lines of "there no such file or folder" for #include <sched.h> and I believe <linux/sched.h> is not the same thing